# HTML5 + discord.js Event Listener

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, discord, discord.js

**What I Want:**
I am trying to make it so when a member is added or removed from staff in my discord it will update it on the website I have. I've tried doing this with node.js, but then I can't use document attributes and etc. Basically I am wondering if this is possible.

**Code JS:**

```js
const headBoardOfDirectors = document.querySelector('#hbod-role');
const boardOfDirectors = document.querySelector('#bod-role');
const headAdmin = document.querySelector('#ha-role');
const seniorAdmin = document.querySelector('#sa-role');
const admin = document.querySelector('#a-role');
const headModerator = document.querySelector('#hm-role');
const moderator = document.querySelector('#m-role');
const trialModerator = document.querySelector('#tm-role');

// Below is just an example of what I am talking about.

staff = [
    bunch of staff roles here
]

if (some member role add or remove event) {
    if (role added or removed is staff) {
        if (role name is Head Board of Directors) {
            headBoardOfDirectors.innerHTML = `${headBoardOfDirectors.innerHTML}\n${member name}`
        }
    }
}
```

**Code HTML:**

```html
        <div id="staff">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th class="main"></th>
                    <th class="main">Staff</th>
                    <th class="main"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Founder</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>killrebeest#1001</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Owner</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>fluffy#9459</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Head of Board of Directors</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td id="hbod-role"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Board of Directors</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="bod-role">
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Head Administration</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="ha-role">
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Senior Administration</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="sa-role">
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Administration</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="a-role">
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Head Moderation</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="hm-role">
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Moderation</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="m-role">
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Trial Moderation</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tm-role">
                    
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**Summary:**
Basically I mainly want to know if this is possible, which I think it most definitly should be. If it is possible, how can the be done, or is there any references that you can answer with to help me solve this issue.
Thanks,
killrebeest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just connect your node.js with your client. I would recommend using EJS. First, you install express, ejs and discord.js by doing `npm i express ejs discord.js`. Then, you can set up your ejs.

`index.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express(); // setting up express

let staff = [ "john doe#1234", "jane doe#4321", "some other name#0001" ]; // example staff members

app.set("view engine", "ejs"); // using ejs

app.get("/", (req, res) => { res.render("index", { staff }); }); // rendering the ejs file

app.listen(80); // listening at port 80 (http://localhost)
```

`views/index.ejs`:

```html
<h1>Our staff</h1>
<ul>
  <% staff.forEach(user => { %> <!-- for each staff member, list it -->
    <li><%= user %></li>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

You need to register a Discord bot. Just go to https://discord.com/developers/applications, create an application, create a bot for said application, enable GUILD_MEMBERS intent and copy the token. You can then invite the bot to your server. From there, you can code the part with discord.js.

`index.js`

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express(); // setting up express

const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS],
}); // intents stuff

const token = "replace with your own bot token";
const serverId = "replace with the id of your server"; // you can get the ids by enabling developer mode (user settings > advanced) and then right clicking on the server or the role
const staffRoleId = "replace with id of the staff role";

app.set("view engine", "ejs"); // using ejs

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const server = await (
    await client.guilds.fetch()
  ) // get all servers
    .find((v) => v.id == serverId) // find your server
    .fetch(); // get the server object

  const staff = (await server.members.fetch()) // get all members
    .filter((v) => v.roles.cache.filter((r) => r.id == staffRoleId).size > 0) // filter out the ones without admin role
    .map((v) => {
      return [v.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png", size: 128 }), v.user.tag];
    }); // avatars and names instead of objects
  res.render("index", { staff });
}); // rendering the ejs file

app.listen(80); // listening at port 80 (http://localhost)

client.login(token); // login
```

You also need to change up the ejs a little bit (I decided to add some styling so it doesn't look completely horrible).

`views/index.ejs`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Our staff</title>
  </head>
  <body
    style="
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 200%;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen,
        Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    "
  >
    <h1 style="margin: 0; padding: 10px; padding-bottom: 0">Our staff</h1>
    <ul>
      <% staff.forEach(user => { %>
      <!-- for each staff member, list it -->
      <li>
        <img
          src="<%= user[0] %>"
          alt="<%= user[1] %>"
          style="border-radius: 50%; width: 32px; height: 32px"
        />
        <%= user[1] %>
      </li>
      <% }); %>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

And with that, you're pretty much done.

Comment: Ah I am surprised I didn't think of this, I recently just installed EJS and all the things you used to help with purchasing products, I will try this when I can. Thanks! I'll make sure to check mark it when I am able to.